Unity Procedural dungeon Generation - connecting rooms with corridors
so I'm working on a rogue like dungeon crawler and I'm struggling to connect my rooms with corridors. I've managed to randomly spawn prefab rooms and found the door locations as you can see in the image ,Current State of the generation. The 3's in the grid simply mean it's a corridor, 1 is just padding for the rooms to stop them from spawning next to each other and the 10 is the door cell any help would be greatly appreciated :)
This is my current Generator class:
[Header("Conditions")]
public int numberOfRooms;
public int Padding;
public int MaxAttempts;
Grid grid;
Testing test;
Vector3 centertingVector;
public List<GameObject> roomsObj;
public GameObject corridorPrefab;
public List<GameObject> AddedRoomsObj;
public List<Room> AddedRooms;
public List<Vector2> occupied;
public List<Vector2> AllDoors;
public List<Vector2> corridors;
int x;
int y;
GameObject chosenRoom;
Vector2[] RoomCells;
Vector2[] Doors;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    //Line of Occupied states surrounding grid to avoid edge case
    test = GetComponent<Testing>();
    test.GenerateGrid();
    grid = test.grid;
    centertingVector = new Vector3(test.CellSize, 0, test.CellSize) / 2;
    //add Boundaries to occupied
    foreach (var cell in grid.bounds)
    {
        occupied.Add(cell);
    }
    

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRooms; i++) 
    {
        int attempts = 0;
        //Loop for attempting to place room if not possible after 10 attempts break generation loop
        
        while (attempts <= MaxAttempts)
        {
            //RNG section
            x = Mathf.RoundToInt(Random.Range(1, grid.width));
            y = Mathf.RoundToInt(Random.Range(1, grid.height));
            chosenRoom = roomsObj[Mathf.RoundToInt(Random.Range(0, roomsObj.Count))];


            //Get roomSize
            Vector2 RoomSize = chosenRoom.GetComponent<Room>().size;
            //CheckPossibleOccupiedCells
            RoomCells = getRoomCells(RoomSize, x, y);

            //LoopOverEach to check if X and Y matches any of the already occupied states
            
            if (DoesOverlap(RoomCells, occupied))
            {
                if (attempts == MaxAttempts)
                {
                    break;
                }
                //if Overlap then 
                Debug.Log($"Attempt:{attempts}: OverLap!");
                attempts++;
                continue;
            }
            break;
            
        }
        if(attempts==MaxAttempts)
        {
            Debug.Log("MaxAttempts reached: Could not place room");
            break;
        }

        // Get spawn pos
        Vector3 pos = grid.GetWorldPos(x, y)+ centertingVector ;
        //Instantiate room prefab
        GameObject room = Instantiate(chosenRoom, pos, Quaternion.identity);
        //Get Room Component of instantiated room
        Room roomComp = room.GetComponent<Room>();
        //Get Door positions

        //Add shit to arrays
        AddedRoomsObj.Add(room);
        AddedRooms.Add(roomComp);
        
        

        //Set new Room positions as occupied
        
        foreach (var item in RoomCells)
        {
            int xPos = (int)item.x;
            int yPos = (int)item.y;
            grid.SetVal(xPos, yPos, 1);
            occupied.Add(new Vector2(xPos, yPos));
        }


        
        Doors = getDoorPositionswithCorridorStartPositions(roomComp.size, x, y, roomComp.DoorPos, corridors);
        
        foreach (var item in Doors)
        {
            AllDoors.Add(item);
        }
        
        
    }
    //SetDoorPosition Values
    foreach (var item in AllDoors)
    {
        grid.SetVal((int)item[0], (int)item[1], 10);
    }

    //put in corridor starts
    foreach (var item in corridors)
    {
        Instantiate(corridorPrefab, grid.GetWorldPos((int)item[0], (int)item[1])+centertingVector, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}


public Vector2[] getDoorPositionswithCorridorStartPositions(Vector2 size, int x, int y,List<int> doorArray,List<Vector2>CorridorArray)
{
    Vector2[] arrayofCoords = new Vector2[doorArray.Count];
    int xRange = (((int)size[0] - 1) / 2);
    int yRange = (((int)size[1] - 1) / 2);

    int f = 0;
    int d = 0;
    //Set occupied cells to occupied
    for (int j = xRange; j >= -xRange; j--)
    {
        for (int k = yRange; k >= -yRange; k--)
        {
            
            foreach (int door in doorArray)
            {
                grid.SetVal(x + j, y + k, 2);
                if (f == door)
                {
                    
                    Vector2 doorPos = new Vector2(x + j, y + k);
                    arrayofCoords[d] = doorPos;
                    Vector2 corridorPos = getCorridorStartPositions(doorPos, new Vector2(x, y));
                    CorridorArray.Add(corridorPos);
                    grid.SetVal((int)corridorPos[0], (int)corridorPos[1], 3);
                    d++;
                }
            }

            f++;

        }
    }
    return arrayofCoords;
}

public Vector2 getCorridorStartPositions(Vector2 doorPos, Vector2 middle)
{
    Vector2 dirVec = (doorPos - middle).normalized;
    return dirVec+doorPos;
}


public Vector2[] getRoomCells(Vector2 size, int x , int y)
{

    Vector2[] arrayofCoords = new Vector2[(int)((size[0]+2*Padding) * (size[1] + 2 * Padding))];
    int xRange = (((int)size[0] - 1) / 2);
    int xRangePadded = xRange+Padding;
    int yRange = (((int)size[1] - 1) / 2);
    int yRangePadded = yRange + Padding;

    int f = 0;
    //Set occupied cells to occupied
    for (int j = xRangePadded; j >= -xRangePadded; j--)
    {
        for (int k = yRangePadded; k >= -yRangePadded; k--)
        {
            arrayofCoords[f] = new Vector2(x+j,y+k);
            //print(arrayofCoords[f]);
            
            f++;
            
        }
    }
    return arrayofCoords;
}

public bool DoesOverlap(Vector2[] roomCells, List<Vector2> occupiedList)
{
    foreach (Vector2 cell in roomCells)
    {
        foreach (var item in occupiedList)
        {
            if (item == cell)
            {
                return true;

            }
        }

    }
    return false;
}


